# Is it true that for any square matrix of real numbers A, there exists a square matrix B, such that AB is a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it true that for any square matrix of real numbers $A$, there exists a square matrix $B$, such that $AB$ is a symmetric matrix?
This is obviously true if $A$ is invertible, but how about if $A$ is not invertible?

Comment: Yes, it is true.  Do you know about transposes of matrices?

Comment: @hardmath oh, you are right, I forgot about transposes. I think A times A transpose will always be symmetric.

Comment: @Sunny88 Please write that as an answer and accept it.  The question will be removed from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $AB$ will be symmetric if we let $B=A^{T}$.

Comment: Similarly, $AB$ will be symmetric if $B=SA^T$ for some symmetric matrix $S$.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply let $B=0$. Then $AB=0$ is symmetric.